# "Talk about something" vs. "talk something"

Tags: difference

Tell me please why the speaker left out the preposition *about* in the following sentences.

> The connective tissue we are going to  discuss in this episode is essential in maintaining homeostasis, so today we are talking blood.

I aware of the idiomatic phrases like *talk money*, *talk shop* or *talk business*, but the example I have given is not only one that does not seem idiomatic. Another similar phrase I have heard is *talk clothes*, that is why I wonder if there any difference between *talk about something* and *talk something* or the preposition *about* has got redundant in modern English.

Comment: It's an idiom: to talk x, for example: You and I need to talk money. It's the same meaning as talk about.